# Tyring to take an xml/xslt table and place it onto a html webpage

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I've recently made up an XML file for a project, accompanied with an XSLT Stylesheet to produce a simple table format once the XML is loaded into my web browser. Alongside, I have an HTML website that I am wanting to be able to take that generated table and place it onto the HTML webpage, so I can then style it accordingly in CSS alongside the rest of the website.

I have a set layout for my HTML website and I'm just simply wanting to move the table generated by the XML/XSLT and have it display on the HTML page.

My XML example page:
***XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="PT.xslt"?>
<!DOCTYPE owners [
<!ELEMENT owners (business+)>
<!ELEMENT business (servicetype, businessname, businesslogo*, servicepic+, url, address, phone+, operatinghours, services, description, rating*, averageprice, currentsales*)>
<!ELEMENT servicetype (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT businessname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT businesslogo (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT servicepic (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT url (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT phone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT operatinghours (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT services (minimumprice, hourlyfee)>
<!ELEMENT minimumprice (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT hourlyfee (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT rating (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT averageprice (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT currentsales (#PCDATA)>
]>
<owners>
<business>
  <servicetype>Physical Training </servicetype>
  <businessname>Big Guns Fitness </businessname>
  <businesslogo>img/logo.jpg</businesslogo>
  <servicepic>service1.jpg</servicepic>
  <url>www.biggunz.net.au</url>
  <address>41 Lekemba Road, Rodstead 2259 NSW Australia </address>
  <phone>0483659150</phone>
  <operatinghours>0900-1700 Monday-Friday</operatinghours>
  <services>
    <minimumprice>$49.99</minimumprice>
    <hourlyfee>$49.99</hourlyfee>
  </services>
  <description>At Big Guns Fitness, we strive to deliver the greatest in expertise and professionalism, delivered to you in world class training and design.</description>
  <rating>4.9/5.0</rating>
  <averageprice>$89.49</averageprice>
  <currentsales>First Workout Free (ends 30th Sept 2019)</currentsales>
</business>

<business>
  <servicetype>Physical Training </servicetype>
  <businessname>Shape Up Bodyworks</businessname>
  <businesslogo>img/logo2.jpg</businesslogo>
  <servicepic>service2.jpg</servicepic>
  <url>www.SUBodyworks.com</url>
  <address>987 Wolka St, Harmet 8792 QLD Australia</address>
  <phone>0487373203</phone>
  <operatinghours>0900-1700 Monday-Thursday, 1000-1700 Friday</operatinghours>
  <services>
    <minimumprice>$19.99</minimumprice>
    <hourlyfee>$39.99</hourlyfee>
  </services>
  <description>Work hard, fast and the right way. Shape Up Bodyworks is the home of athletes, right in the heart of Peak Physical Training.</description>
  <rating>4.2/5.0</rating>
  <averageprice>$29.99</averageprice>
  <currentsales>Buy two PT sessions, get one half price</currentsales>
</business>

<business>
  <servicetype>Physical Training </servicetype>
  <businessname>Orion Supplements</businessname>
  <businesslogo>img/logo3.jpg</businesslogo>
  <servicepic>service3.png</servicepic>
  <url>www.OrionSupplements.fitness.au</url>
  <address>21 Kendall St, Albourke 2232 NSW Australia</address>
  <phone>0429487304</phone>
  <operatinghours>0800-1600 Monday-Wednesday, 0900-1700 Thursday-Friday</operatinghours>
  <services>
    <minimumprice>$9.99</minimumprice>
    <hourlyfee>$24.95</hourlyfee>
  </services>
  <description>Orion Supplements is the pinnacle of Physical Training and development supplements. A mix of pre-workout, and an actual workout. Fitness, just hit a whole nother level</description>
  <rating>5.0/5.0</rating>
  <averageprice>$22.49</averageprice>
  <currentsales>2x 2ltr Pre-workout shakers for $50</currentsales>
</business>
</owners>
```

My XSLT: ***XSLT***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
          <head>
              <title>Businesses</title>
          </head>
          <body>

               <table border="1"  style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                 <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                     <th>Business Name</th>
                     <th>Service Type</th>
                     <th>Website</th>
                     <th>Business Logo</th>
                     <th>Service Picture</th>
                     <th>Address</th>
                     <th>Phone</th>
                     <th>Operating Hours</th>
                     <th>Minimum Price</th>
                     <th>Hourly Fee</th>
                     <th>Average Price</th>
                     <th>Description</th>
                     <th>Rating</th>
                     <th>Current Sales</th>
                 </tr>
                 <xsl:for-each select="owners/business">
                  <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="businessname"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="servicetype"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="url"/></td>
                    <td><img src="img/logo.jpg" width="100" height="100"/></td>
                    <td><img src="img/service1.jpg" width="250" height="120"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="address"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="operatinghours"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="services/minimumprice"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="services/hourlyfee"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="averageprice"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="currentsales"/></td>
                  </tr>
                 </xsl:for-each>
               </table>
          </body>
      </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Well, although you say " I'm just simply wanting to move the table generated by the XML/XSLT", in reality, your XSLT generates more than a table, it generates a complete, separate HTML document. So you can embed it into another HTML document with an `iframe` element or `object` element but applying the same CSS styles to two different HTML documents is usually done by separating the CSS out into a .css file and then have all HTML documents use it with a `link` element.

Comment: Because the use of such "brick" template, you won't be able to extend the transformation. Besides @MartinHonnen good comments, you could also use your stylesheet to get the complete HTML document and then extract the table to put it into another HTML document. That can be done with javascript in the client side or XSLT in the server/cliente side.